# Java programming cant get my while statement to loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the user to give input and then after everything from all the cases was read out to them, re-loop to the `output.displayMainMenu();` until they were to enter 4 to exit the program.

```
output.displayMainMenu();
int entry = keyboard.nextInt();
while(entry >= 1 || entry <=4) {
    output.displayMainMenu();
    switch(entry) {
        case 1: 
            output.displayStockChoices(portfolio);
            portfolio.editPostion();
            portfolio.displayPositions();
            break;
        case 2:
            portfolio.updateCurrentPrice();
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print(investor.toString() + "Account Balance: "  +portfolio.calcTotalAccountValue());
            break;
        case 4: 
            System.out.print("Done.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("please enter 1-4!");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet there's an infinite loop here, because `entry` is never reassigned in the loop.

Comment: || is logical OR, so one of those two conditions is always true.  && is logical AND and what you are looking for.

Comment: You have a `break;` outside of your switch. This breaks out of your loop. But there's several issues here, such as your while loop condition and with getting the user input also.

Comment: You probably would have caught the issue that @AntonH mentions if you had formatted the code [yourself].  It sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: And entry <= 4, if you want to exit on 4, that should be `entry < 4`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a do-while loop because the code inside the loop need to be ran at least one time. I agree with @AntonH, that are several issues in this code. I rewrote it considering the mentioned issues.

```
int entry = 0;
do {
    output.displayMainMenu();
    try {
        entry = keyboard.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("Invalid input. ");
    }

    switch (entry) {
        case 1:
            output.displayStockChoices(portfolio);
            portfolio.editPosition();
            portfolio.displayPositions();
            break;
        case 2:
            portfolio.updateCurrentPrice();
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print(investor.toString() + "Account Balance: "
                    + portfolio.calcTotalAccountValue());
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Done.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("please enter 1-4!");
    }

} while (entry >= 1 && entry < 4);
// Don't forget to close Scanner object when program finish
keyboard.close();
```